# How to set the value of loadBalancerKey in ribbon or Feign

Tags: java, load-balancing, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, netflix-ribbon

In Spring Cloud, I'm using Ribbon or Feign as the client API, and we have a server cluster registered in Eureka. In my case, I want to use the specific key to determine which server I want to call, eg: `server-A` has two instances, `localhost:8001` and `localhost:8002`, and I want to call `8001` by setting the `loadBalancerKey` to `8001`, after that I can write my customized balance rule class to choose which server I can call like below:

```
public class MyConfigBalanceRule extends ClientConfigEnabledRoundRobinRule {
    @Override
    public Server choose(Object key) {
        List<Server> serverList = getLoadBalancer().getAllServers();
        for (Server srv : serverList) {
            if (srv.getPort == key) {
                return srv;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your Feign/Ribbon client located in a Spring Boot application?

Comment: @Indra Basak yes,it is a spring boot app

Comment: @spencergibb FYI